# Angular 4 ng-content select not working on dynamically created transcluded elements

Tags: javascript, angular, transclusion

I am using the `ComponentFactoryResolver` to dynamically create an element to be inserted into my template, which uses `ng-content` for transclusion.

It all works wonderfully until I add a `select` attribute to my `ng-content`. Please see [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TXYZSwmMqXn6KXXoK6oU?p=preview) which demonstrates the problem. If I remove the `content-top` attribute from my `HeaderComponent` template on line 63 of `app.ts`, the template renders as expected.

I do however need to use `select` because there are two different template fragments to be injected so I can't simply remove it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If i remove `content-top` attribute on line 63 i don't see the difference. If i remove `select` from `ng-content` i see that `HeaderComponent` is rendered

Comment: Angular transcludes only direct children. Try  `select="[content-host]"` https://plnkr.co/edit/DXCBACANjufthKMgNeSE?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, you're quite right, I meant remove the `select` from line 18. I need to be able to select elements that are replaced in the `ng-template` and `<ng-template content-host>` is replaced anyway. The `<h1 top-content>` will be the top level in this case.

Comment: `because there are two different template fragments to be injected so I can't simply remove it.` Can you expand your example? Which fragments will be also injected?

Comment: @yurzui Please take a look at this new plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/TXYZSwmMqXn6KXXoK6oU?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/YfX6CPLSFflhY1Qkiipt?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot @yurzui, that works a treat. I had to do a bit of reading on ng-template but it's solved my problem! Put your plunker link in an answer and I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transclusion in angular will work only with direct children. One way to do it working might be using `ngTemplateOutlet` to lift up content from dynamic component:

```
<some-other-component>
    <ng-template content-host></ng-template>
    <ng-template top-content [ngTemplateOutlet]="topContent"></ng-template>
    <ng-template bottom-content [ngTemplateOutlet]="bottomContent"></ng-template>
</some-other-component>
```

**component.ts**

```
topContent: TemplateRef<any>;
bottomContent: TemplateRef<any>

const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
const instance = componentRef.instance;
componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

this.topContent = instance.templates.find(x => x.place === 'top-content').templateRef;
this.bottomContent = instance.templates.find(x => x.place === 'bottom-content').templateRef;
```

where templates property is declared on your dynamic component

```
@ViewChildren(TranscludeMeToDirective) templates: QueryList<TranscludeMeToDirective>;
```

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/YfX6CPLSFflhY1Qkiipt?p=preview)